# Qt5: Запрос представления в QTableView

Tags: c++, mysql, qt5

Есть некоторые представления. Нужно вывести их в QTableView, а так же запрос всех представления существующих в БД, результат это

Делаю:

```
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("адрес");
    db.setDatabaseName("xelfebix");
    db.setUserName("xelfebix");
    db.setPassword("пароль");
    if(!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open    database:" << db.lastError();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Connection established";
    }
    QTableView view;
    QSqlQueryModel model;
    model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM `ТехПроцесс`;");
    qDebug() << model.lastError();
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.show();
}
```

В итоге вся таблица пустая. Что я делаю не так и как поправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас

```
QSqlDatabase db;
QTableView view;
QSqlQueryModel model;
```

уничтожаются при выходе из конструктора, сделайте их переменными класса.

Comment: Сделал. Всё работает.